# How to split the string value for SQL

Tags: vb6

I want to splite the value with single quote

Dim usr as string

```
usr = "01,AF,BF,CD,DF,FE,"
```

I want to pass this string to sql query

Sql Query

```
Select * from table1 where code in ('" & usr & "')
```

Output nothing is displaying,  bcoz passing the string in sql is not proper

Sql will not understand '01,AF,BF,CD,DF,FE,', Instead of this we need to pass
the string like this

```
user = 'AF', 'BF', 'CD', 'FE'
```

How to do this.

Need vb6 code help

Comment: Holy sql injection vulnerability batman!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```
usr = Replace(Left(usr, Len(usr) - 1), ",", "','")
sql = "Select * from table1 where code in ('" & usr & "')"
```

Comment: Have to downvote for the sql injection issue. This is not code that anyone should emulate.

Comment: @Joel: Oh please. The question is more about how to format a string than the fineries of how SQL should be implemented in code. And given that an `IN` clause is being used, it would take jumping through a tortuous hoop to implement passing parameters. Moreover, the codes used are clearly not user generated, so the possibilities of SQL injection being an issue, in this particular case, are vanishingly remote.

Comment: I would agree with that if sql injection was just a "finery", instead of one of most exploited security issues there is.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = split(usr, ",") 
usr = join(arr,"','")
```

trim off the double quotes and replace with single quotes

Comment: it is coming like this  AF', 'BF', 'CD', 'FE', ' i want to display like this 'AF', 'BF', 'CD', 'FE'